# I need to Update if exist else Insert with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

What is the most efficient way to update a row if it exists or add it if doesn't?

I am using Linq to SQL and have read a [few posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100068/linq-to-sql-insert-if-non-existent) on it, but none that are current or that solve it without multiple database calls or an old framework.  Currently I just insert and if there is a duplicate the statement gives an error, `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint`.

The reason i need it to be quick is that it will eventually be hitting many thousands of records.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using Entity Framework instead of LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Is there any reason why? It wouldn't be hard to setup I just have a lot done without using it so far.

Comment: You can't do this without database roundtrips, unless you fetch all PK values in advance, check in memory and keep your fingers crossed that no duplicates get added by concurrent users after the check and before the commit. I happened to give a similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20156644/861716).

Comment: This table is only written to by a single function and the function is only called on a scheduled basis. So I don't have to worry about race conditions (right?).

Comment: Also, if you're concerned about performance you could increase your rate ten- to twenty-fold by not using an ORM and using pure SQL for this specific operation instead. It makes a real difference where needed.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Knowing that round-trip calls were needed in order to do this, I loaded the table's primary key values.  Then before calling `db.SaveChanges` I added the following code:

```
if (checklist.Contains(tempstats))
             {
                db.Stats.Add(tempstats);
             }
```